# Covert to Actionscript 3 Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have created some code in Actionscript 3 following various tutorials which is a simple media player linked to an XML file for the source information. I have found out though I need to use actionscript classes for the code and wondered is their a way to convert it to classes or does anyone know of a tutorial in actionscript 3 for creating a media player based on classes? My code is below:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlloaded);

var xml:XML = new XML();
var amountofvid:Number=0;
var currentvideo:Number=0;

btn_prev.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, prevvid);
btn_next.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, nextvid);

loader.load(new URLRequest('videos.xml'));

function xmlloaded (e:Event) {
    xml=XML(e.target.data);
    amountofvid=xml.video.length ()-1;
    changevid();
}

function nextvid (e:Event) {
    currentvideo++;
    changevid();
}

function prevvid (e:Event) {
    currentvideo--;
    changevid();
}

function changevid():void {
    var cv:Number=Math.abs(currentvideo);

    if (cv>amountofvid) {
        currentvideo=cv=0;
    }
    if (currentvideo<0) {
        currentvideo=cv=amountofvid;
    }

    vid.source = xml.video.@src[cv];
    title.text = xml.video.@title[cv];

}
```

Any ideas?

Update, thanks for the help guys both helped loads wish I could pick you both a solved answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a quick conversion of your code to a classe.

```
package  {

import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;    

public class mediaPlayer extends Sprite {

    private var loader:URLLoader;
    private var xml:XML;
    private var amountofvid:Number=0;
    private var currentvideo:Number=0;

    public function mediaPlayer() {

        loader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlloaded);
        btn_prev.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, prevvid);
        btn_next.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, nextvid);
        loader.load(new URLRequest('videos.xml'));

    }

    private function xmlloaded (e:Event) {
        xml = new XML();
        xml=XML(e.target.data);
        amountofvid=xml.video.length()-1;
        changevid();
    }

    public function nextvid (e:Event) {
        currentvideo++;
        changevid();
    }

    public function prevvid (e:Event) {
        currentvideo--;
        changevid();
    }

    private function changevid():void {
        var cv:Number=Math.abs(currentvideo);

        if (cv>amountofvid) {
            currentvideo=cv=0;
        }

        if (currentvideo<0) {
            currentvideo=cv=amountofvid;
        }

        vid.source = xml.video.@src[cv];
        title.text = xml.video.@title[cv];

    }

}

}
```

I assumed that it will be associated to a sprite so i extended it as such. If you want to associated the classe to something else, you will want to change this line :

```
public class mediaPlayer extends Sprite {
```

I kept both nextvid and prevvid methods public (meaning you can access it from another level, a parent for example) and your other methods and variables private (accessible from this level only). You might want to change that to suit your need.

For a  startup tutorial on how classes works, i would suggest this one on GoToAndLearn.com
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=43

m.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for your help mate, got there in the end just having an issue with the title for some reason the title name for every video is showing as ido?

Answer (score 2):

Getting away from the timeline and embracing some basic OOP structure is the single best thing you can do as a budding flash developer, programmer, or earnest student. Its can be a deep subject, but the sooner you get started figuring it out the better. The googles will explain everything.

At any rate - you have most of what you need to write this procedure into a class. Check out the comments for a brief explanation:

```
// package encloses the class and identifies its scope
package you.com.app
{
    //imports
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ... declare your class, whatever it may extend and any interfaces
     */

    public class MediaPlayer extends Sprite
    {
        // variables now include an access modifier to define their scope (private, here)
        private var xml             :XML;
        private var amountofvid     :Number=0;
        private var currentvideo    :Number=0;
        private var loader          :URLLoader;
        private var vid             :MovieClip; //or video component or whatever
        private var title           :TextField;
        private var btn_prev        :SimpleButton;
        private var btn_next        :SimpleButton;
        private var currentvideo    :int;

        /**
         * constructor - must match class name. returns statement omitted
         */
        public function MediaPlayer()
        {
            // call superclass
            super();
            //initialize procedure
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
           //build display list
            assembleDisplayObjects();

            //grab data
            retreiveData();

        }

        private function retreiveData():void
        {
            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlloaded);
            loader.load(new URLRequest('videos.xml')); 
        }

        private function xmlloaded (e:Event):void  
        {
            xml = new XML();
            xml=XML(e.target.data);
            amountofvid=xml.video.length ()-1;
            changevid();

            addEventHandlers(); //when data has loaded, activate clickables
        }

        private function assembleDisplayObjects():void
        {
            // create or instantiate display objects, and into the display list
            // adjust x,y values as needed
            vid = new MovieClip();
            this.addChild(vid);

            title = new TextField();
            this.addChild(title);

            btn_next = new SimpleButton();
            this.addChild(btn_next);

            btn_prev = new SimpleButton();
            this.addChild(btn_prev);
        }

        private function addEventHandlers():void
        {
            //centralized event listener control

            btn_prev.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, prevvid);
            btn_next.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, nextvid);
        }

        private function nextvid (e:Event):void 
        {
            currentvideo++;
            changevid();
        }

        private function prevvid (e:Event):void  
        {
            currentvideo--;
            changevid();
        }

        private function changevid():void 
        {
            var cv:Number=Math.abs(currentvideo);

            if (cv>amountofvid) {
                currentvideo=cv=0;
            }
            if (currentvideo<0) {
                currentvideo=cv=amountofvid;
            }

            vid.source = xml.video.@src[cv];
            title.text = xml.video.@title[cv];
        }

    }   

}
```

I haven't tested this and it's probably not error free, but it is the basic package/class structure and should get you going.

I'd highly recommend Shupe / Rossers "Learning Actionscript 3.0" as a great intro to the subject, and Mook's "Essential Actionscript 3.0" as a comprehensive reference. And google. Lots of google.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Bosworth99, thanks for getting back to me, im in the UK so was asleep when you replied :) Im having some errors running the code and have done some googleing to work it out but cant work out how to fix the problems. You couldn't download the files from http://markhaynes.me/flash/ for me could you and have a look what's going wrong?

Comment: Actually got it working my bad :) Just stuck on the title of the video for some reason its coming up ido rather than the title of the video :S

Comment: Another update for some reason out of all the alphabet it will only display the letters adgilno.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Cheers